# Calculation of thermodynamic variables using partial derivatives

Tags: thermodynamics, differentiation

Perhaps someone can help with the question of calculating derivatives of quantities from some more general functions using partial derivatives? This question arises especially often in thermodynamics. For example, let us have an explicit form of dependence of internal energy of a body on macroscopic parameters $U(P, V, T)$ and we need to calculate the isochoric heat capacity.
The latter is related to the internal energy by the well-known relation
$$
C_{V} = \left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_{V}.
$$

Formally, there should be no difficulties in calculating such a derivative. However, it should be noted that the macroscopic parameters themselves are related to each other (this is actually why the partial derivative is used). Therefore, using the equation of state we can express one quantity through the other, and substitute the corresponding expression in $U(P, V, T)$. The result will be some other function $U'(P, V, T)$. It is obvious that the derivative calculated from a "shaded" function (as a minimum) may differ from a non-shaded one. The validity of this assertion can be verified by examining, for example, the system
$$
\begin{cases}
f(x, y) = x \cdot y^{2}, \\
x - y = 0.
\end{cases}
$$
Using the relationship $y(x)$ we can rewrite the function in the form $f_{1}=x^{2} y$ or $f_{2}=x^{3}$ or $f_{3}=x^{5/2} \sqrt{y}$ (with an additional condition are all equivalent forms of recording, correct me if I'm wrong). Accordingly $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = y^{2}$, $\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x} = 2xy$ etc.

This raises the question of how to "correctly" choose the "right kind" for the function $U(P,V,T)$?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to calculate $$C_V=\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_V\ ,$$ notice that the derivative is with respect to $T$ keeping $V$ constant, so the "correct" way to do this is to get rid of $P$ in $U(P,V,T)$ using the equation of state $P=P(V,T)$ and taking the derivative of the resulting function $U(V,T)$.

Comment: Your definition of Cp is incorrect.  Cp is the partial derivative of enthalpy H with respect to temperature at constant pressure.  On the other hand, the first part of your answer is great.

Comment: Oh, you're right @ChetMiller. My mistake. Thanks!

Comment: You may be right about the fact that taking the partial derivative requires one of the three variables to be excluded by the condition of the equation of state. But is there any explicit explanation for this action?

Let me explain. To calculate the same thermal conductivity (although isobaric) you can use entropy.
$$
C_{P} = T (\partial S / \partial T) _{P}
$$
The entropy itself is generally speaking a function of $S(U, P, T, V)$. One free variable can be excluded by the state eq., but the other (in the general case) will allow for variations.

Comment: @Sssur, the simplest thermodynamic systems need three variables to determine equilibrium states. The equation of state imposes a constraint so that only two of those variables are independent. The entropy $S$, just as $U$, can be thought of as depending [only on two variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(classical_thermodynamics)#Entropy_measurement) since it is a state function. The same happens with all [thermodynamic potentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_potential), they only depend on two variables.

Comment: So to calculate derivatives as $(\partial X/\partial Y)_Z$, express $X$ as a function of only $Y$ and $Z$ and get rid of every other variable using relations between them.